# gulp build not outputing file. Where did I go wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, babeljs

I would like to know why my gulp task is not outputing any files.

Here is my task:

```
import gulp from 'gulp';
import babelify from 'babelify';
import sourcemaps from 'gulp-sourcemaps';
import browserify from 'browserify';
import source from 'vinyl-source-stream';

gulp.task('build', function () {
  return browserify({entries: './src/app/index.jsx'})
    .transform(babelify, {presets: [ 'es2015', 'react' ]})
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

`gulpfile.babel.js` is in the app root, and I have the following directory structure in my app.

src

|- app

```
|- index.jsx
```

I tried to created /dist myself, but still no `bundle.js` is generated inside it.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I had a duplicated definition of `build` task that overrode the one given in the question. I wish gulp warned me about duplicated task definition.